# If we have collection of beads of $x$ different colors, $3$ beads for each color, how many ways can we string all $3x$ beads on a single line?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Since there are $3$ beads of $x$ amount of colors we have $3(x!)$

Since there are $3$ of each type of beads we have $3!$ equivalence classes,

therefore the amount of ways to string the beads should be $\dfrac{3(x!)}{3!}$ right?

Or have I made a mistake and it's possible to double the ways by flipping the line or something? Making it multiplied by $2$ at the end? I see that kind of thing all the time and it always gets me

Answer (score 2):

If the the beads were to be distinct we have $(3x)!$ ways
Now for each type of bead we have $3!$ equivalence classes
$\therefore$ As there are x type of beads the total no. of equivalence classes will be $(3!)^x$
$\therefore$ The total no. of ways to string the beads is $\frac{(3x)!}{(3!)^x}$
(Assuming flipping the string isn't allowed)

---

If flipping the string is allowed then we shall make 2 cases:
**Case 1:** $x=1$
Obviously there is only $1$ way here.
**Case 2:** $x\geq 2$
Here after flipping any arrangement of the beads the arrangement will be changed as otherwise there will be a color not having any fixed position (i.e. in the middle of the string) which will have equal no. of beads on either side of the string implying that $2$ divides $3$ which is false.
$\therefore$ The total no. of ways here will be our original answer by $2$ i.e. $\frac{(3x)!}{2(3!)^x}$

Comment: Why is there an exponent x in the denominator? Because there's 3! for every color of bead?

Comment: @SteveLuna Yes. To get some hold on it you could solve this by brute force for the case $x=2$.